# Remote JVM Robot Invocation

Tags: java, swing, testing, rmi

Has anyone heard of the ability to grab a java.awt.Robot from an external JVM? Or even how to serve one?

I'd really like to be able to run some Automated GUI tests on an application that is already running. Could I set up an RMI Gateway on the application and execute Robot commands/tests by proxy? Or is there already a solution for this?

Example : Application A is a monolithic massive application, with many maven dependencies. It runs, dedicated, on a server.

I'd like to be able to put some code in Application A so that I can execute from Test Application B - on the same host, while A is still running - Mouse / Keyboard commands using a java.awt.Robot instance taken from Application A.

I guess it's almost driving rather than testing the application - a bit like speeding up certain sections from a dashboard (like logging in, creating a new file etc)

Edit : I've maybe mis-understood, I was hoping for the same functionality as the Robot class in FEST, but I get the feeling it's a far superior version compared to java.awt.Robot. I guess the same question still stands, but it'd be for the FEST Robot.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/java-remote-control/, http://sourceforge.net/projects/jrdesktop/?_test=b

Comment: I am aware that this cannot answer your inter-app communication. Can't you do VNC and also run the test software remote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's out, it can be nice to use [Robotium remote control](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RemoteControl).

In the meanwhile, depending on what you really want, a small socket client / server program pair sending clicks and mouse moves is not so hard to implement.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds as if I'll have to roll-my-own, I'm just surprised this fire hasn't been fought yet.

Comment: me too ! But what do you need that for ? Maybe you could achieve it with vnc or other desktop protocole.

Comment: It sounds as if I'm being mis-understood actually. I'm going to update my question with an example...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something on RMI+Robot. I used one system as a remote control (client) to control another system (server). [Source.](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxzbHZnYW5lc2g5MHxneDoyYmMxZWM4Mjc1MTNhMDI0)

Please let me know if it solves your problem. Dont use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc.